# Working with current tab from Popup chrome extention

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that will collect some data from currently opened tab on Google chrome.

I also use a popup in my extension to provide a control interface (buttons and stuff).

I need to be able to do the following:

1) Read source code of currently opened tab.
2) To be able to scroll down window content (using the code of course) .

If I could only get access to a javascript "window" object of currently opened tab , that would be enough.

But I'm open for another suggestions .
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use `document` in a content_script. Content scripts are defined in the manifest.json. In your case you should set **"run_at": "document_end"**, so the dom is fully loaded when your script is called.

For more informations about content scripts and chrome extension development you find an easy to use guide from google - http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Answer (score 0):

Code from popup won't be able to access directly to window objects from displayed tabs. You have to use a content script which will be able to send the source code of opened tab to the background page. This content script will also be able to scroll the window of opened tab.